# How do you format a number as a Text() string value with thousandths separator, using SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I see references to NSNumber and NumberFormatter on lots of pages, but none of it works for SwiftUI. I just need to make it so `100000` gets formatted as `"100,000"`. Any ideas?

Comment: can't you just make a func that gets number and return formatted string?  or is there something else that you require?

Comment: Why doesn't NumberFormatter work, the question is quite unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I do not know what issue you were facing, because can not tell without the code. but this works.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import Foundation

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var num =  5432
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text("\(getFormattedNumber() ?? "undefined")")
                .onTapGesture {
                    num += Int.random(in: 3000...800000)
                }
        }
    }
    
    func getFormattedNumber() -> String? {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        let s2 = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: num))
        return s2
    } 
}
```